# JdbcMutableAclService + HSQLDB = BadSqlGrammarException when updating ACL

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, hsqldb

I'm using Spring ACL together with MySQL and it works fine. However, when in integration tests I use HSQLDB engine, when I call `aclService.updateAcl(myAcl)` it throws the following exception(s):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
  PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar 
  [insert into acl_entry (acl_object_identity, ace_order, sid, mask, granting,
  audit_success, audit_failure)values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is
  java.sql.SQLException: statement is not in batch mode
...
java.sql.SQLException: statement is not in batch mode
...
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: statement is not in batch mode
```

The whole code snippet is:

```
ObjectIdentity oi = new ObjectIdentityImpl(domainObject);
MutableAcl acl = aclService.createAcl(oi);
acl.setOwner(new PrincipalSid(SYSTEM_PRINCIPAL_SID));
if (parentObject != null) {
    Acl parent = aclService.readAclById(new ObjectIdentityImpl(parentObject));
    acl.setParent(parent);
}
aclService.updateAcl(acl);
```

The `aclService` field is instance of class `JdbcMutableAclService`. Note that on MySQL everything works fine.

Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE.

**EDIT:**
Actually the exception was thrown only if the `acl.getEntries()` returns empty list (as the ACL has just been created - it contains no ACEs). I fixed the problem by extending the default implementation of `JdbcMutableAclService` and overridding the `updateAcl()` method which causes the problem by calling `createEntries()` on empty list. I still don't know the real cause of this problem, but I managed to get it working. Here is my quick solution:

```
@Override
public MutableAcl updateAcl(MutableAcl acl) throws NotFoundException {
    if (acl.getEntries().size() > 0) {
        return super.updateAcl(acl);
    }

    Assert.notNull(acl.getId(), "Object Identity doesn't provide an identifier");

    // Change the mutable columns in acl_object_identity
    updateObjectIdentity(acl);

    // Retrieve the ACL via superclass (ensures cache registration, proper retrieval etc)
    return (MutableAcl)super.readAclById(acl.getObjectIdentity());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my general experience (I honestly never tried Spring ACL with HSQLDB) and according to [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/forums/forum/73673/topic/4580493) when PreparedStatement is used with HSQLDB it is mandatory to add a batch. Therefore, I guess you can't test Spring ACL on HSQLDB.